# Enque script not working for jQuery in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I always, always have trouble getting jQuery to work in wordpress.

I really need some clarification and explination on just how this thing works.

Here is my code and I can't seem to see what is wrong with it.

In the functions.php file:

```
function my_init() {
if (!is_admin()) {
    // comment out the next two lines to load the local copy of jQuery
    // wp_deregister_script('jquery'); 
    // wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js', false, '1.3.2'); 
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
} } add_action('init', 'my_init');
```

And this is in my footer before I call my other jQuery scripts:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
```

Comment: I have this problem also.I mean i load it somehow but i always get trouble's with wp_enqueue_script.

Comment: Can you describe what kind of problems you are having with this?

Comment: Yes jQuery isn't loading. I have removed this and added a script tag into the document and it loads fine. But with just this... doesn't load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're some answers in [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21007/trying-to-enqueue-script-in-wordpress) also.

I've encountered this also in the past, and I usually don't even use the wordpress own jquery if needed. Because the serverside google method is faster. This code below has to work.

**functions.php**

```
<?php

function google_jquery() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
} 

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'google_jquery');

?>
```

Make sure that wp_head(); is in your **header.php** file.

**header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<title><?php wp_title(); ?> <?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></title>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<?php if ( is_singular() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

You don't need to call the other jquery scripts in the footer that way. If you're enqueueing lets say jquery UI scripts then make sure you have
 wp_footer(); in your **footer.php** file.

**footer.php**

```
<?php 
//Footer scripts
wp_footer(); 
?>
</body>
</html>
```